Short story/clip about a lonely man who buys a female android companion
I'm trying to identify a short clip and/or a short story. I am thinking this may be around 10 years old.
A lonely man moves into an apartment.  He buys a beautiful humanoid android female companion and has her programmed with jealousy included.  Just as they are getting settled, he gets a knock at his apt door: it is a new beautiful female neighbor introducing herself. He tries to hide the android, but she is not happy ...

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

"She is not happy..." and what? She commits murder? She explodes? She bakes a cake?

Closed captions, "[angry baking continues]"
